# Sync or Async Methods in Abstract Class

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I think about using the following `abstract class` as a base for database migrations:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public abstract class MigrationBase
{
    public abstract string Name { get; }
    public abstract string Description { get; }
    public abstract int FromVersion { get; }
    public abstract int ToVersion { get; }
    public abstract void Apply();
    public abstract Task ApplyAsync();
}
```

Now, depending on the underlaying database system a concrete migration will be written for, it may make more sense to implement the `void Apply` or the `Task ApplyAsync` method. I see the following options:

1. If I decide just having one of both abstract methods, I force the developer implementing the concrete migration to do it wrong either in the [one](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/04/13/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/) or [the other](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/24/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/) way "in 50% of the cases".
2. If I decide having both abstract methods, I force him doing it wrong whenever the database system doesn't offer both possibilities.
3. Having a `MigrationBase`, `SyncMigrationBase` and `AsyncMigrationBase` and using typecasts everywhere doesn't seem reasonable to me.
4. Is there a better option I'm currently missing?

Now you might say I could just choose option two because ADO.Net offers sync and async methods and *in most cases* the database adapters will offer both variants. Is there a better solution if you look at the more general problem without ADO.Net in mind?
If I chose option two, should I provide a preimplemented version of the `Task ApplyAsync` similar to what Microsoft did with `System.IO.Stream.ReadAsync` while considering what Stephen Toub has written? If yes, what else should I pay attention to?

Comment: Then I'd need i.e. `bool` properties `SupportsSync` and `SupportsAsync` which does not seem like good design to mee too...

Comment: Or, without the properties: I don't think using the main feature of a class should result in a exception beeing thrown in many cases, so that it can just be used in try-catch-blocks to decide which variant will be used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `ApplyAsync` alone, and delete the other method.

> If I decide just having one of both abstract methods, I force the developer implementing the concrete migration to do it wrong either in the one or the other way

If the user needs to implement an `async` method from an interface or an abstract class, but he must do everything synchronously, there is absolutely no problem substituting an `async` method returning a `Task` with a synchronous method, which returns a completed task constructed from result.

Your code, on the other hand, always performs calls as if they were asynchronous.

> If I decide having both abstract methods, I force him doing it wrong whenever the database system doesn't offer both possibilities.

That's right, exposing both methods is a worse alternative.

> Having a `MigrationBase`, `SyncMigrationBase` and `AsyncMigrationBase` and using typecasts everywhere doesn't seem reasonable to me.

I think you are right, adding a subclass for what can be "folded" into the base class does look like more effort than is necessary.

Comment: Wouldn't it be quite confusing to call the method `...Async` then? Wouldn't I break the pattern by not doing so?

Comment: @Georg Which pattern would you be breaking? You've a async method with a ...Async name which is correct.

Comment: I'd break the pattern by not calling it Async. But I'd expect a method called Async to be truly asynchronous too.

Comment: @GeorgJung To me, a base method name `XyzAsync` means that I have an option of implementing it as `async`. In fact, I would estimate that 10..15% of `async` methods in my current project are implemented as synchronous, because they implement an interface with an `XyzAsync` method in it, but they don't need to do anything asynchronously, so they call `Task.FromResult`.

Comment: @Georg It is up to the class that implements the method to make it actually run async. If this implementation is synchronous then either: 1) The code is so short for that implementation that no one will care that it is synchronous. OR 2) The synchronous implementation needs to be made async by for example sending it to the threadpool.

Comment: @EpicSam According to [Stephen Toub](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/24/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/) your option two would be the wrong way.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight But if I do this I hide the real nature of the method from the caller who might want to call the method using `Task.Run`; maybe its the best option though :/

Comment: @GeorgJung That's perfectly OK for the caller to call the method with `Task.Run`, because the caller should not think about the details of method's implementation, except perhaps in the context of performance of his own method that makes the call. Programmers who start by implementing your abstract class synchronously may refactor their code when async facilities become available to their implementation, and provide a true async method to you, as long as you give them an option to do so.

Comment: @Georg In the article you linked, read the part about ReadAsync and WriteAsync in the Guideline section. This covers your situation as well.