# How to execute an async method inside an abstract class from another call back method in a different class

Tags: c#, async-await, task, abstract-class

I have a concrete class call AncSubscriberWrapper and it has a call back method

```
    public Task OnUnshownCounterUpdatedAsync(long counter)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

and also I have an abstract class call BasePageViewModel and it has an async method

```
    protected async void GetUnseenNotificationsCount()
    {
        UnseenNotificationCount  = await m_ancSubscriberWrapper.TryGetNotificationCountAsync(NotificationStatus.Delivered | NotificationStatus.Created);
    }
```

Classes paths are like below inside the project.

> ./src/Visit.Common/Services/AncSubscriberWrapper.cs
>   ./src/Visit.Common/ViewModels/PageViewModels/BasePageViewModel.cs

***What I need is to execute the GetUnseenNotificationsCount() method from OnUnshownCounterUpdatedAsync() method.***

How can I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41242056/sync-or-async-methods-in-abstract-class

Comment: You can just call one method from the other. Bigger problem here is that there's no way to discover when `GetUnseenNotificationsCount` is finished (because it's `void` not `Task` returning)

Comment: You need to provide more clarity regarding your class design, especially the abstract class, calling it from anywhere is not the challenge but anything beside an event having a void as return for the method is a bad design, also Async shall be all the way to the top, otherwise you have a caller blocked as in your case `OnUnshownCounterUpdatedAsync` is a non async method. In short your current design has lot of shortcomings which need to be addressed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is one way I was able to reach my goal. I am not sure this is the right way of doing this though.

How I achieved my goal is using an EventHandler.

Create an interface (IAncSubscriberWrapper) for AncSubscriberWrapper class

```
public interface IAncSubscriberWrapper
{
    event EventHandler UnshownNotificationCounterUpdated;
}
```

and implements it like below

```
public class AncSubscriberWrapper : NotificationCenterFacade, IAncSubscriberWrapper
```

Then implement the interface member inside the AncSubscriberWrapper class

```
public event EventHandler UnshownNotificationCounterUpdated;
```

and also invoke method inside the OnUnshownCounterUpdatedAsync method

```
public Task OnUnshownCounterUpdatedAsync(long counter)
{
    UnshownNotificationCounterUpdated?.Invoke(this, null);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Then go to BasePageViewModel and register and unregister listeners.

```
public void Initialize()
{
    m_ancSubscriberWrapper.UnshownNotificationCounterUpdated += OnUnshownNotificationCounterUpdated;
}

public void Teardown()
{
    m_ancSubscriberWrapper.UnshownNotificationCounterUpdated -= OnUnshownNotificationCounterUpdated;
}
```

Since BasePageViewModel is an abstract class, which ever the concrete class that use it, will override the methods. (Following code snippet is not directly related to this question, but for understanding the design on my code basis)

```
/*
* BaseContainerViewController is only accepting TPageViewModel generic type of classes only.
* TPageViewModel inherits BasePageViewModel and BaseContainerViewController inherits BaseViewController
* That's what following line is all about
*/

public abstract class BaseContainerViewController<TPageViewModel> : BaseViewController where TPageViewModel : BasePageViewModel
```

and

```
public class WardListViewController : BaseContainerViewController<WardListPageViewModel>
```

Back to the final part of the answer. Add following method inside BasePageViewModel class and that will complete the process.

```
protected virtual void OnUnshownNotificationCounterUpdated(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) 
{
    GetUnseenNotificationsCount();
}
```